# FEM : energy minimization VS PDE solving

Tags: finite-element, optimization, pde, simulation, computer-vision

### Engineering FEM

When I studied engineering, I learned the traditional approach for finite elements for elasticity. The point was to solve the PDE $-div(\sigma)=f$ as:

1. Multiply your PDE with a test function, integrate, find the weak form: $\int \sigma(u): \epsilon(v) - \int v f = 0$
2. Interpolate $u=\sum_i u_i N_i$, set $v=\sum_j N_j$
3. Assemble the linear system and solve it to find $u_i$

### Computer graphics FEM

Then I enrolled in a PhD in computer graphics, and the way they do FEM for simulation is totally different. The point is to minimize the integrated energy with Newton Raphson

1. Given the integrated energy $\int \psi$, compute the gradient $G = \nabla_u  \int \psi$ and the hessian $H = \nabla_{u} \nabla_{u} \int \psi$
2. Discretize the domain, for each element compute $H_{elt}$ and $G_{elt}$
3. Assemble the full linear system, and apply Newton Raphson to find displacements s.t. $\int \psi$ is minimal.

The computer graphics way has the advantage to be easy to implement. Whatever energy you chose, the point is to find a minimum.

The engineering way is harder to implement, but has a strong math background (Lax theorems to ensure convergence).

### So here are my questions

1. Are both ways equivalent ?
2. The computer graphics way is an optimization problem, the engineering way is a numerical analysis problem. How do we apply the convergence theorems (stability, consistency, etc) in the energy minimization case ?

Comment: 1.) Yes, both are equivalent. The second method is known as the energy method; the derivations follow variational calculus. We will arrive at the weak form, by taking the first derivative of the energy functional. There should not be any difference between the two approaches in terms of implementation since the element matrices and vectors would be exactly the same.

Comment: 2.) Once you get the first variation, which is nothing but the weak form, you can apply all the consistency and stability criteria of the weak forms.
The energy method (the computer graphics way) works only when the energy function, $\psi$, exists. But the weak form approach (engineering approach) works even for those cases for which it is not possible to devise an energy function, e.g. hypoelastic materials.

Comment: @ChennaK this probably should be an answer?

Comment: Thanks ! About implementation, the energy method seems easier to me, take its gradient / hessian and integrate it, voilà. While with the weak form approach you have to do some integration my parts, apply stoke theorem etc, which gets quite messy when your energy is complex.